# What happens if an object manages to reset/delete a unique_ptr of itself?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I am having quite some trouble writing this question, so I'm just going to show a minimal example.

Suppose this is a class `FruitHandler` that handles an object of type `Fruit` using a unique_ptr, something like this:

```cpp
class FruitHandler {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Fruit> m_fruit;

public:
    FruitHandler() : m_fruit{std::make_unique<Fruit>(*this)} {}

    void some_func() {
        m_fruit.func();
    }

    void clear_fruit() {
        m_fruit.reset();
    }
}
```

And this is a class Fruit:

```cpp
class Fruit {
private:
    FruitHandler &m_handler;

public:
    Fruit(FruitHandler &handler) : m_handler{handler} {}
    
    void func() {
        m_handler.clear_fruit();
        // Let's say I'm accessing more member variables after this
    }
}
```

I had something like this in my code with a few more levels of indirection between the handler and the handled object.
There were a few more objects relying on the object and one of those things (or the handler) was causing a crash which I managed to solve (not by avoiding the thing I wrote) and now I'm just wondering out of interest what would happen if you would delete an object in this way. Is this somewhat similar to writing `delete this`? Is it undefined behavior?

Comment: This *is* `delete this`, just with extra steps.

Comment: Ah so this isn't undefined behavior (as long as you don't somehow manage to make a unique_ptr point to non dynamic memory and then you have other problems) but you shouldn't access members after it, right? @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica

Comment: Pretty much, yes.